# Python, create a dataframe of elementwise max tuples from multiple dataframes of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple dataframes of tuples in the form:

```
df1 =

   col1  col2  col3
0  (1,1) (2,1) (3,1)
1  (1,1) (2,1) (6,1)
2  (1,1) (1,1) (5,1)

df2 =

   col1  col2  col3
0  (2,2) (1,2) (4,2)
1  (1,2) (2,2) (3,2)
2  (3,2) (2,2) (3,2)
```

I want to compare the dataframes element-wise and create a new dataframe containing tuples based on the max value of the first element in the tuples, and carry the complete tuple with it to the new dataframe as in the following:

```
dfmax =

   col1  col2  col3
0  (2,2) (2,1) (4,2)
1  (1,1) (2,1) (6,1)
2  (3,2) (2,2) (5,1)
```

Preferably I would like to perform this without iterating.

Comment: did you try `np.maximum(df1,df2)`?

Comment: The quick check worked!  That was easy.  Thx!  Let me roll it into the full code and see if I'm good.  Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: At second thought, it might not be what you asked for. For example: `(2,1)` in `df1` and `(2,2)` in `df2` will produce `(2,2)` in the output.

Comment: I found an error in column 1 that I fixed.  Regarding your comment, for my needs it will be ok if there are multiple locations with the same max value in first position and it cascades to the secondary positions, etc.  It would be nice if there was a function to control that without disassembling the df tuples into components and reassembling.